# automatic asp.net windows authentication from WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: asp.net, wpf, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a WPF desktop application which has a WebBrowser control.

In this control I want to load a thirth party website which uses asp.net windows authentication.

Can I pass the username and password which I already have in the desktop application to the website so the user does not have to enter the credentials again?

Comment: If you happen to find a solution to this, please do post it here. I'm trying to do the same thing and it seems no one can tell how to do it...